# How to add "\n " in this string 12-MARCH-2019 after Month End . I want this 12-MARCH\n-2019 in java

Tags: java, string

How to add `"\n"`  in this string `"12-MARCH-2019"` after Month End . I want this `"12-MARCH\n-2019"` in java

I want to add `"\n`

Comment: You want to add `\n` and not a linebreak, don't you? Then do what @ShubhamMittal answered. Otherwise please add more information to your question. Thank you.

Comment: @abkayani try adding more details about what you are trying to do as this does not give much details allow others to help solve your problem

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
public static String modify(String str) {
    int pos = str.lastIndexOf('-');
    return str.substring(0, pos) + '\\n' + str.substring(pos); // or '\n' for a new line
}
```

Answer (score -1):

please use something like that

```
System.out.println("12-MARCH\\n-2019 ")
```

please put \n instead of \n

Comment: I want to add in string

Answer (score -1):

-

Put this
System.out.println("12-mach"+\n+"2019");

- This \n make anew line the output is 
  12-march

2019